# Adding graphics and image to a PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, picturebox

I have a `PictureBox` control. I want to put an image in this `PictureBox`.

This I did:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"D:\test.jpg");
```

I don't want the image to fill the entire `PictureBox`.

Next, I want to draw graphics on the `PictureBox` which I do using the following code:

```
Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();

g.DrawArc(....);
g.DrawLine(....);
```

It should be something as shown in the following picture:

[image]

In the above picture, the image should be only in the bounds of the blue rectangle, around which I want to draw the graphics. How to draw an image?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Take a look at this example : https://kishordgupta.wordpress.com/2011/02/18/c-tips-how-to-draw-on-a-picturebox-image-using-mouse-by-c/

Comment: Image [size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.size.aspx) defines the *bounds*.

Comment: Use `SizeMode = CenterImage`. To draw __onto__ the surface use the `Paint` event. To draw __into__ the Image see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27337825/picturebox-paintevent-with-other-method/27341797?s=3|0.0377#27341797) - To combine resizing the Image and drawing into it use a `DrawImage` overload with two rectangles in the`Paint` event!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Paint event or by creating Graphics object as you are doing and then draw circle and line as below:
*Example code snippet:*

```
   private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(
            new Pen(Color.Red,2f), 
            new Point(0,0), 
            new Point(pictureBox1.Size.Width, pictureBox1.Size.Height ));

        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(
            new Pen(Color.Red, 2f),
            0,0, pictureBox1.Size.Width, pictureBox1.Size.Height  );
    }
```

and you can draw image using below methods:

```
g.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(10, 10, 200, 200));
```

Reference these threads:
[how to draw drawings in picture box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537090/how-to-draw-drawings-in-picture-box)
[How do I draw a circle and line in the picturebox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729751/how-do-i-draw-a-circle-and-line-in-the-picturebox)
[Drawing on picture box images](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/318900/Drawing-on-picture-box-images)
[FAQ: How do I draw an image respectively on the PictureBox control and Image object?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/eeaeae99-10a5-46da-b23b-6f1b1db30c0a/faq-how-do-i-draw-an-image-respectively-on-the-picturebox-control-and-image-object?forum=vbgeneral)